# How to get rid of zombie villagers in a world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I don't care about having regular zombies around, but my sister and I really dislike the new villager zombie skins of 1.9. Is there any way to ban them temporarily or even permanently in a world? I don't have a custom map like one of the questions before. I just want to clear the villager zombies. How is this done?

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't possible unless you have a resource pack that changes their models and skins into regular zombies

Answer (score 5):

You can use command blocks on a clock to mark zombie villagers and remove them.

Labeling zombies if they are zombie villagers:

```
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=Zombie,tag=!ZombieVillager] add ZombieVillager {IsVillager:1b}
```

Teleporting them to the void to either kill or force them to despawn, which avoids item drops all over the place (as the items fall in the void to be deleted):

```
/tp @e[type=Zombie,tag=ZombieVillager] ~ -64 ~
```

You can also use the `/kill` command to speed up the dying process:

```
/kill @e[type=Zombie,tag=ZombieVillager]
```

Comment: I can't check right now, but shouldn't you be able to set `IsVillager:0b` to turn them into regular zombies instead of killing them?

Comment: @MrLemon That's a very good point indeed! Antoine Hejlík has that covered now.

Comment: ok...so I am guessing the same procedure also goes with regular zombies...right? @Skylinerw

Comment: @JoshRimell Yes, you can set `IsVillager` to 0 to exclude zombie villagers instead.

Answer (score 4):

### Texture pack way (easier)

You can make your own texture pack, where you will alter zombie villager texture by the normal one. Be sure to do it to baby villager, too.

Other textures don't need to be altered, texture packs are intelligent and will alter only things that they have different - all other textures will remain default ones.

**Pros:** 
You can use it with even other texture packs, you just need to order them properly. Also you can use them on other servers as well without being OP.

**Cons:** You have to study how texture packs are made, if you don't know it already. However there is A LOT of tutorials around. :)

### **Command way (you need to be OP)**

In MC 1.9 you can have automatic command block with

```
/kill @e[type=Zombie]
```

But that will kill all zombies. The difference is only in NBT tag, and that difference the /kill command cannot distinguish.

So you will need to deal with it. Setup Scoreboard objective:

```
/scoreboard objectives add ZombieVillager dummy ZombieVillager
```

Now you will need One "always running" commandblock (blue one?) and one chain commandblock (green one?)
First one - settuped that it runs always in loop, without redstone:

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Zombie] ZombieVillager 1 {IsVillager:1b}
```

Second one - conditional = yes (so it executes only when first does) , chained, no redstone needed:

```
/kill @e[type=Zombie,score_ZombieVillager=1]
```

Or alter zombies:

```
/entitydata @e[type=Zombie,score_ZombieVillager=1] {IsVillager:0b}
```

Be sure that you have those CB's in "everytime loaded area" -> chunk where /setworldspawn is.

Comment: you can also search other textures packs where you like the zombies villagers :)